# How do I replace the default source folders for gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am new to Gradle and I have a source code location different than what Gradle expects.

Gradle expects to find the production source code under `src/main/java` and your test source code under `src/main/resources`.  How do I configure Gradle to a different source code?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to add few lines to `build.gradle`:

To replace the default source folders, you will want to use srcDirs instead, which takes an array of the path.

```
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs = ['src/java']
        main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/resources']
    }
```

Another way of doing it is:

```
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/java'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/resources'
            }
        }
    }
```

The same thing is applicable to test folder too.

Comment: I have replaced default directory `src/main/java` with `src/java`, though gradle build is trying to find `src/main/java` path to compile java path. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Another way of doing it is:" is incorrect.  That adds to the sets instead of replacing them.